# What are the possible alternatives of global variables and which one is best one?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

What are the possible alternatives of global variables and which one is best one?
As I have heard that use of global variable is not good.
I am working on WCF application and there is possibility of multiple instances of WCF and little chances that I will use concurrency.

This WCF service will be deployed to a server and then a client will send a series of request but request one has some unique request which should be maintained in remaining requests.

Comment: Technically, there's no concept of global variable in C#... The nearest concept may be a public static member of a class.

Comment: Can you describe your situation and why you need global variables?

Comment: Do you mean public vs private?

Comment: Question edited. Please have a look on it.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by keeping a global variable in a WCF Service ? Do you want to retain contextual information or something for a series of calls ?

Comment: I want to share some information during a session.

Comment: @TimCastelijns is right. Static member and instance member have both justifications to exists. You may need to share data between instances, and thus static is required. But static often lead to concurency issue, memory leaks or other trap if you don't use it wisely. Anyways, you question is too broad (and will probably be closed). Please describe a specific problem. Your question can't be answered as is.

Comment: 'WCF and little chances that I will use concurrency' this statement is plain wrong. Each call to wcf service can be executed on new thread.

Comment: Is there any session or 'context' type class which can be used to store information during multiple calls during a single session?

Comment: @Rafal that depends on the threading mode; it *can* be, but calls from a single caller can also be synchronized / serialized

Comment: Have you considered, InstanceContextMode http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.instancecontextmode(v=vs.110).aspx. See if it helps...

Comment: Call me crazy, but I'd be tempted to do it all manually: have a method that issues a `Guid` as a session identifier, that I need to pass into the session-based methods, which serves as a key to an external session store. This then scales to any size cluster, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, there are no global variables but static properties/fields of a class are something that is close to what meant.

Be **very careful** of using any static properties/fields (static members that hold state) in WCF code. Each WCF call is a separate thread in the same process and as such they will share the values of static properties/fields. This may lead to unpredictable results and hard to debug problems.

> ...little chances that I will use concurrency

Your code is almost always concurrent if it's running in WCF. Be extremely careful.

You could use a threading mode that would help you in this case (single concurrency mode) but you still need to design your system carefully.

Comment: I think static properties/fields is best option.

Answer (score 1):

The "more global" a variable is, the easier it is to access it. However, as soon as every component in your application accesses it, your application depends more and more on that variable. You can't change the variable, because it's being used everywhere.

Automated tests become ugly and require modification with each modification to your application, and you can't reuse any component that uses the global variable.

If you do want to use "global variables" (public static members) try to limit its use as much as possible, for instance when you're creating an instance of a class, supply the value of the variable to its constructor, so that class won't depend on the "global" reference.

In more detail, say you have this class:

```
public class MyUsefulClass 
{
    public void DoSomethingUseful()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The value is: " + MyGlobalVariables.Variable1);
    }
}

new MyUsefulClass().DoSomethingUseful();
```

Then you can only use `MyUsefulclass` if you can reference `MyGlobalVariables.Variable1`. You can't reuse `MyUsefulclass` in a different project that does not have these globals.

Rewriting it to:

```
public class MyUsefulClass 
{
    public MyUsefulClass(string valueToWrite)
    {
        ValueToWrite = valueToWrite;
    }

    public string ValueToWrite { get; private set; }

    public void DoSomethingUseful()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The value is: " + ValueToWrite);
    }
}

new MyUsefulClass(MyGlobalVariables.Variable1).DoSomethingUseful();
new MyUsefulClass("I don't need globals!").DoSomethingUseful();
```

In this case, you can reuse `MyUsefulClass` without requiring the globals to be present in your new project. You still have a "global"-ish variable, but with this modification less code depends on "it being global".

Comment: I understand ur answer but cannot understand the part of your question "so that class won't depend on the "global" reference." Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @operation Updated my answer with a sample.